# Storing Error Logs from Apache and PHP as values

Tags: php, apache

These days I was thinking about some interesting features to create an authomatic diagnostic platform. Basically, I want to create an algoritm that could store error Logs from a debugger to a Data Base, like the date and time of ocurrence too, to further analysis and treatments. Initially, I thought to make something in PHP, registering Logs from Apache and PHP itself.

There are some way to obtain these logs from debugger as some sort of values?

Thanks.

Comment: Why Debugger? You can use a LoggerInterface like Monolog.

Comment: A cron job to parse the access and error log files for interesting information might make sense.  Running live server web requests through a debugger instead of normally doesn't make sense.  Adding activity logging for things of interest (database changes by users, login failures, ...?) might make sense too.  We log actions of interest to database tables -- the db server  handles concurrent users properly and lets us use queries.

Comment: Just to throw it out there, PHP and Monolog both support writing to syslog which is pretty standard, and syslog can optionally push remotely to a central server

Comment: Also take a look at Linux' rsyslog system. It allows a fine grain of routing of logging messages to various backends based on filtering by source and log level.